# Delete a node's pointer in LinkedList in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

Today i'm praticing deleting a node implementation in LinkedList and this problem occur. This is my LinkedList.h file:

```
#pragma once
template <class Data>
class Node
{
public:
    Node();
    Node(Data newData, Node<Data>* newNext);
    ~Node();
    Node<Data>* next;
    Data data;
};


template<class Data>
class LinkedList
{
public:
    LinkedList();
    ~LinkedList();
    int size();
    bool put(Data data,int pos);
    bool del(int pos);
    void show();

private:
    typedef Node<Data>* nodePtr;
    nodePtr head;
    int N;
    bool isEmpty();
    nodePtr getPosition(int pos);
};
```

Then my LinkedList.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "LinkedList.h"

using namespace std;

template<class Data>
Node<Data>::Node() {
    next = NULL;
}

template<class Data>
Node<Data>::Node(Data newData, Node * newNext)
{
    data = newData;
    next = newNext;
}

template<class Data>
Node<Data>::~Node()
{
    delete next;
}


template<class Data>
LinkedList<Data>::LinkedList() {
    head = NULL;
    N = 0;
}

template<class Data>
LinkedList<Data>::~LinkedList()
{
    delete head;
}

template<class Data>
int LinkedList<Data>::size()
{
    return N;
}

template<class Data>
bool LinkedList<Data>::isEmpty()
{
    return N == 0;
}

template<class Data>
Node<Data>* LinkedList<Data>::getPosition(int pos)
{
    nodePtr temp = head;
    if (pos > N-1) pos = N-1;
    for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++)
        temp = temp->next;
    return temp;
}

template<class Data>
bool LinkedList<Data>::put(Data data, int pos)
{
    nodePtr add;
    if (pos == 0) {
        add = new Node<Data>(data, head);
        head = add;
    }
    else{
        nodePtr pPre = getPosition(pos-1);
        nodePtr pCur = pPre->next;
        add = new Node<Data>(data, pCur);
        pPre->next = add;
    }
    N++;
    return true;
}

template<class Data>
bool LinkedList<Data>::del(int pos)
{
    if (isEmpty()) return false;
    if (pos == 0) {
        nodePtr pTemp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete pTemp; //error
    }
    else {
        nodePtr pPre = getPosition(pos - 1);
        nodePtr pCur = pPre->next;
        pPre->next = pCur->next;
        delete pCur; //error
    }
    N--;
    return true;
}

template<class Data>
void LinkedList<Data>::show()
{
    for (nodePtr pTemp = head; pTemp != NULL; pTemp = pTemp->next)
        cout << pTemp->data;
}

void main() {
    LinkedList<int> list;
    list.put(0, 0);
    list.put(1, 0);
    list.put(2, 0);
    list.put(3, 0);
    list.put(4, 0);
    list.del(0);
    list.show();
}
```

the program works if i comment these line (but i think it'll lead to memory leak), if i let these line there it cause "program has stopped working" and a random number in console window.
So can you guys please help me how to delete these pointer in correctly way?
Sorry for previous ambiguous question.
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: What error occured if you do not commenting it? Why you not check pCur to NULL ? Can you show the Node class?

Comment: Please provide all code required to replicate the error. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can we see the method used to create nodes? Especially, I'm curious about how the memory pointed by `pCur` was reserved.

Answer (score 0):

Oh i just firgure out my mistake. Because of my ~Node() method here:

```
template<class Data>
Node<Data>::~Node()
{
    delete next;
}
```

so when i delete a Node, it delete all pointer it linked to in a row, causing that error. Anyway thanks for helping guys.